# How to select specific substring length based on a filter

Tags: powershell, substring

I have multiple CSV files with different names, containing today's date, customer number, and then the extension. For example:

```
2019-01-23 XYZF-105.csv
2019-01-23 ABCD-205.csv
2019-01-23 Different nonstandard name.csv
2019-01-23 ##ABCD-305(Trial).csv
```

I would like to get the part of the name where it contains the customer number only, like ABCD-305.

Tried using a substring to select 8 characters right from the dot, but that doesn't work for those that have suffix like (Trial).
Neither it work 11 characters from the beginning, as it will include the ##.
Also, it has to avoid the nonstandard names.

I used

```
$allitems = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Downloads\Customers\*.csv'
$res = @()
foreach ($item in $allitems){
    $item = $item.Name.substring($item.Name.Length - 12,8)
    $res += $Item
}
```

This way, for the proper names I get good results, but only if the name of the CSV is like 2019-01-23 ABCD-205.csv.

What should be the way to skip the date, skip the .csv extension and get only results with 8 characters, that have a dash after the 4th character?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (PSv3+ syntax):

```
$res = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Downloads\Customers\*.csv).Name | 
         Select-String -CaseSensitive '\b[A-Z]{4}-\d{3}\b' |
           ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Value }
```

- `(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Downloads\Customers\*.csv).Name` outputs the file names of all CSV files in dir. `C:\Downloads\Customers`
- `Select-String -CaseSensitive '\b[A-Z]{4}-\d{3}\b'` uses case-sensitive regex (regular-expression) matching to only select file names that contain 4 (`{4}`) uppercase chars. `[A-Z]`, followed by `-`, followed by 3 digits (`\d`), on word boundaries (`\b`)
- The `ForEach-Object` script block then outputs the part of each matching file name that matched the regex (`$_.Matches[0].Value`), so that only the relevant portions of matching file names are collected in `$res`, as an array.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @silverbackbg; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good time to use regex.
See https://regex101.com/r/AH00n6/1

and understand the following regex:

```
.*\s[#]*([A-Z]{4}-[0-9]{3}).*.csv
```

This is a little extra to capture just the names, but gives more insight into how to control the regex.

Comment: Kory, you are amazing. Thanks for the link. I will bookmark it right away.